# How to copy all the github commit ids between two software releases into a txt file?

Tags: github

I have two versions of code with the old one named "CMSSW_11_2_0_pre3" and new one named "CMSSW_11_2_0_pre5". There is a difference of about 170 pull requests with about 500 commits  between the two. Please see this link:
https://github.com/cms-sw/cmssw/releases/CMSSW_11_2_0_pre5

I want to list all the 500 commit ids into a txt file. Doing it manually by copying and pasting each id from the website itself will take lot of time. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy actually:

```sh
git log --pretty=format:"%H" CMSSW_11_2_0_pre3..CMSSW_11_2_0_pre5 > file
```